# SelectedValue property for a Autocomplete User Control in GridView

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls

First off, forgive my English.  I created one user control with Textbox and AutoCompleteExtender controls, and it's working fine.  Now, I wanted to reflect my textbox similar to a dropdownlist.  When i kept the user control in a GridView and accessed the value through a hidden field, i'm getting "0" value.  How can i read hidden field value in my page?

**UserControl.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Code File="UserControl.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="UserControl" %> <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %> 

<script type="text/java script">
    function DispValue(sender, e) {
        alert(e.get_value() + "   : user control");
        document.getElementById(hiddenFieldName.Client ID).value = e.get_value();       
    }
     </script> 
<asp:Hidden Field ID="hdnValue" runat="server" Value="0" /> 
<asp:Text Box ID="txtName" runat="server" Text=""> </asp:Text Box> 
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="ACEName" TargetControlID="txtName" runat="server"
        CompletionInterval="10" MinimumPrefixLength="1" Service Method="Get Name"
        Service Path="UserControlWebServices.asmx" OnClientItemSelected="DispValue">      
</cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

**UserControl.ascx.cs**

```
public partial class UserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl 
{    
    protected void page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ACEName.ContextKey = "1";
    }

    public String SelectedValue
    {
        get { return this.hdnValue.Value; }
    }

    public String SelectedText
    {
        get { return this.Name.Text; }
    } 
}
```

**MyAspxPage.aspx**

```
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControl.ascx" TagPrefix="puc" TagName="UserControl" %> <head runat="server">
    <title></title> </head> <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">  
    <asp:Script Manager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
    </asp:Script Manager>
    <asp:Grid View ID="gvPatient" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnDataBound="GridPatient_DataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:Template Field>
                <Header Template>
                    Patient Name
                </Header Template>
                <Item Template>
                    <puc:UserControl ID="pucPatient1" runat="server" />
                </Item Template>
            </asp:Template Field>   </Columns>
    </asp:Grid View>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnClick="Save" Text="Save" OnClientClick="return StartUpload();" />
    </form> 
  </body> 
</HTML>
```

**MyAspxPage.cs**

```
    DataTable dt;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("col1");
            dt.Columns.Add("col2");
            dt.Columns.Add("col3");
            dt.Columns.Add("col4");
            dt.Columns.Add("col5");
            dt.Columns.Add("col6");


            if (Session["dt"] == null)
            {
                dt = AddRow(dt);
                gvPatient.DataSource = dt;
                gvPatient.DataBind();
                Session["dt"] = dt;
                //ViewState["dt"] = dt;
            }
            else
                dt = (DataTable)Session["dt"];//ViewState["dt"];

        }
    }

    private DataTable AddRow(DataTable dt)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "";
            dr[1] = "";
            dr[2] = "";
            dr[3] = "";
            dr[4] = "";
            dr[5] = "";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
    }

 protected void GridPatient_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow item in gvPatient.Rows)
        {
            UserControl ptuc = (UserControl)item.FindControl("pucPatient1");
            string id = ptuc.SelectedValue;
         }
    }

 public void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow item in gvPatient.Rows)
        {
            if (item.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                UserControl ptuc = (UserControl)item.FindControl("pucPatient1");
                string id = ptuc.SelectedValue;//getting null value.
                string patientName = ptuc.SelectedText;
             }
        }    }
```

this is all what i did.

i'm stuck with this please help me.

Sharanamma

Comment: Please edit your question to include the markup for the code you're having problems with.  Then we can try and help you out =)

Comment: Is the hidden field in the GridView too?

Comment: no i kept only in UserControl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hi friends 
>   Thanks for your valuable reply, 
>   actually its working fine, but small change in UserControl
>   clientselected event side,i,e
>
> **UserControl.ascx**   function DispValue(sender, e) {
>           var source = sender.get_id();
>           var lastIndex = source.lastIndexOf("_");
>           var replaced = source.substring(0, lastIndex + 1);
>           var hdnId = replaced + "hdnPatientNumber";
>           document.getElementById(hdnId).value = e.get_value();
>       }
>
> **UserControl.ascx.cs**
>    public String SelectedValue
>       {
>           get { return Request.Form[this.hdnPatientNumber.UniqueID];
>   }
>       }
>
> Thanking you all, 
>  regards,
>  Sharanamma.